# Run Django on Apache server on Windows 7

Tags: django, windows, apache, static, nltk

Yes, I know that Windows is not good for running Apache, but I have no choice, since the server runs other things that I don't control..

Here's my problem:
I've setted Django on Apache, on localhost (localhost:8000), the application runs perfectly, all libraries are there, etc..
But when I use the Apache host(say localhost/textmining), I have two problems:

- My static files doesn't work, so none of the bootstrap and javascript of the project works
- It keeps getting this error on NLTK:

.

```
LookupError at /select_text

**********************************************************************
  Resource [93mpunkt[0m not found.
  Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:

  [31m>>> import nltk
  >>> nltk.download('punkt')
  [0m
  Searched in:
    - 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\config\\systemprofile/nltk_data'
    - 'C:\\nltk_data'
    - 'D:\\nltk_data'
    - 'E:\\nltk_data'
    - 'c:\\program files (x86)\\python36-32\\nltk_data'
    - 'c:\\program files (x86)\\python36-32\\lib\\nltk_data'
    - 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\config\\systemprofile\\AppData\\Roaming\\nltk_data'
    - ''
```

But, as I've said, I've done the nltk.download('punkt') on and admin prompt of command, on localhost it works fine..already restarted the apache and still nothing ;/

I think that the part of static files are missing configuration, but can't find how to do it..so if someone can help me with the static and media configuration on apache, I really would apprechiate.

My settings of Django:

```
STATIC_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')

STATIC_URL = '/static/' # You may find this is already defined as such.

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    STATIC_PATH,
)
```

Apache:

```
DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/htdocs"
<Directory "${SRVROOT}/htdocs">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride None

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "${SRVROOT}/htdocs/textmining/textMiningProject">
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

The Media is not configured yet on django, since it's not needed at this time, but the static is needed and doesn't work...

Edit 2: The static settings on apache..

```
Alias /static/ "${SRVROOT}/htdocs/textmining/static"

<Directory "${SRVROOT}/htdocs/textmining/static">
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and I did a `python manage.py collectstatic` ,
still doesn't load the static files

Comment: How can we help when you haven't shown the configuration?

Comment: @DanielRoseman sorry about that, posted when leaving work on Friday, just got access again today..I've edited the question with the settings that I have now..if you can help, please

Comment: You don't seem to have done anything to configure static files in Apache. This is all [perfectly well covered in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files).

Comment: I've put the settings following the documentation, still doesnt work, @DanielRoseman